# Android layout design- first element focus issue

Tags: android, focus

When I am designing android layout.The first time all element's focusing order is fine.But after changing focus for first time the order is change *[as a bellow image]*.
(At first it  select `Number 1 EditText`,but now it's goes to select `Number 2 EditText`),**How it's happen ?**(below image shown that change).

[image]

In Windows there have GUI option to set tab order,but **how to set first focus element in android design time?**

Comment: post the xml for that

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin thanks dude,when I was going to copy that xml I saw this line in EditText2 `<requestFocus />` then i remove it and set EditText1 element.

Comment: Ya that was I thought as well `requestFocus `

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin how it is set automatically ?

Comment: Nope, I think the last edittext that you added will have that tag, and yes remove it to have focus to the Number 1 edittext

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin is there any GUI option to select that `requestFocus`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to set focus to EditText in your way(in your sequence) then use this code

```
android:nextFocusDown="@+id/id_of_next_EditText"
```

in this way you can set who will get the nest focus on pressing enter(return) key
and use `<requestFocus>` in EditText where you want focus when layout is dislayed

Answer (score 1):

RequestFocus:

in Program

```
      edittext1.requestFocus();
```

in XML file

```
<EditText>
<requestFocus />
 </EditText>
```

Ref `<requestFocus>`
Any element representing a View object can include this empty element, which gives its parent initial focus on the screen. You can have only one of these elements per file.

Answer (score 0):

I'll removed `<requestFocus />` in EditText2 and set it back to relevant element. But I don't know how it's happen automatically :(

Answer (score 0):

Set `<requestFocus/>` in first edit text only :

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <requestFocus /> 
</EditText>
```